# Energy-information correlation

Tags: complex-systems

A man walks into an unlit room and sits down in front of an old video player and  TV. He watches a music video. This takes 5 minutes. He then leaves the room immediately. We call this event (A)

The following day he comes back but someone has adjusted the video player so he watches the same video in slow motion. This takes ten minutes. He then leaves the room immediately. We call this event (B)

Since it is the same man and the same video-tape is the overall energy change in the room after (A) and (B) the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct relationship between energy and information, so the question doesn't have a "yes or no" answer.  See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0501/0501014.pdf) to get a better understanding of the topic(s).  It would be more meaningful to ask if the amount of *entropy* changes due to information flow according to your scenario.

It's certainly going to change due to the thermodynamic inefficiencies of the video projection electronics, but that isn't what you're asking about because it has essentially nothing to do with the information content of the video or the viewer's brain.